# Changing mocked useLocation returned value with mockImplementation

Tags: reactjs, testing

I am mocking useLocation from react-router-dom in my test. I want to change returned value in one of them to check if input becomes disabled. Can I change it with mockImplementation on there is other way since that one doesn't work for me ? I am probably doing something wrong.

**test**

```
jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("react-router-dom"), // use actual for all non-hook parts
  useLocation: () => ({
    pathname: "/",
  }),
}));
const mockedPath = require("react-router-dom");

test("is disabled when on todo subpage", () => {
    mockedPath.mockImplementation(() => ({
      useLocation: () => ({
        pathname: "/todo/4RhdwMMMTcbJKvouqnWb",
      }),
    }));
    //when
    render(
      <SearchbarWithProviders
        language="en"
        setSearch={mockSetState}
        search=""
      />
    );
    //then
    expect(screen.getByTestId("search-input")).toBeDisabled();
  });
```

Comment: Generally, mocking the location hook is not how you test navigation. The easiest way is to actually let it navigate and use standard `window.location` and `history.push` to check the value or change it. Mocking the hooks themselves is brittle moving forward and will give lower confidence.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the ability to `SearchbarWithProviders` to use `MemoryRouter` (probably pass it down as a prop) and then pass down also the `initialEntries` prop.

See https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/MemoryRouter/initialentries-array.

Or you could literally change the history in the test before render:

```
history.pushState({}, '', '/todo/4RhdwMMMTcbJKvouqnWb')
```

Either of these will be more robust than mocking the hook. You would be testing whats actually happening and using a first class API to achieve it.